# Is there a way to "change" the name of my dog?

Tags: dogs, behavior, pet-names

I want to change my dog's name because back then, I *somehow* liked it. but now I think it is too hard to pronounce. If it's possible, how hard will it be?

I know that changing the name is instant, but what I mean is the association of my dog to the new name. Also, they don't recognize their own names which seems odd. Will it be hard, if possible, to associate my dog to their new name?

Comment: Yes, though I am also asking how hard it will be (on average) to teach a dog a new name.

Comment: The other post also contains advice for when your dog doesn't react to their name. If they don't even recognize their old names, we cannot possibly give you any estimate how long it will take to learn the new one. Just keep in mind that dogs are bad at distinguishing language, so if you have several dogs, their nbames must not sound similar (like Hanni & Nanni) and they should not sound similar to usual words you use every day.